# Update multiple records in same table

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to update multiple SalesQuotationLines the match Quotation Id X.

```
salesQuotationLine = salesQuotationLine::find(quotationId,true);

salesQuotationLine.selectForUpdate(true);

if(salesQuotationLine) {

 ttsBegin;

SalesQuotationLine.Field = newFieldValue;
salesQuotationLine.update();

ttscommit;
```

The problem is, this is only updating the first record that is found within the `find` method.

How can I make sure, all records that match the QuotationID are being updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
while select forupdate salesQuotationLine 
where salesQuotationLine.quotationId == quotationId 
{
    salesQuotationLine..Field = newFieldValue;
    ttsbegin;
    salesQuotationLine.update();
    ttscommit;
}
```

Or can Use _update_recordset_

```
ttsbegin;
update_recordset salesQuotationLine
setting
Field = newFieldValue
where salesQuotationLine.quotationId == quotationId 
ttscommit;
```

I hope to understock the question.

Answer (score 0):

Dynanics AX 2012 provides way to use X++ SQL statements to enhance performance. This option is `update_recordset` which enables you to update multiple rows in a single trip to the server:

```
update_recordset salesQuotationLine
setting
    Field = newFieldValue
where salesQuotationLine.quotationId == quotationId;
```